# Can Scala infer the actual type from the return type actually expected by the caller?

Tags: scala

I have a following question. Our project has a lot of code, that runs tests in Scala. And there is a lot of code, that fills the fields like this:

```scala
production.setProduct(new Product)
production.getProduct.setUuid("b1253a77-0585-291f-57a4-53319e897866")
production.setSubProduct(new SubProduct)
production.getSubProduct.setUuid("89a877fa-ddb3-3009-bb24-735ba9f7281c")
```

Eventually, I grew tired from this code, since all those fields are actually subclasses of the basic class that has the uuid field, so, after thinking a while, I wrote the auxiliary function like this:

```scala
def createUuid[T <: GenericEntity](uuid: String)(implicit m : Manifest[T]) : T = {
    val constructor = m.runtimeClass.getConstructors()(0)
    val instance = constructor.newInstance().asInstanceOf[T]
    instance.setUuid(uuid)
    instance
}
```

Now, my code got two times shorter, since now I can write something like this:

```scala
production.setProduct(createUuid[Product]("b1253a77-0585-291f-57a4-53319e897866"))
production.setSubProduct(createUuid[SubProduct]("89a877fa-ddb3-3009-bb24-735ba9f7281c"))
```

That's good, but I am wondering, if I could somehow implement the function createUuid so the last bit would like this:

```scala
// Is that really possible?
production.setProduct(createUuid("b1253a77-0585-291f-57a4-53319e897866"))
production.setSubProduct(createUuid("89a877fa-ddb3-3009-bb24-735ba9f7281c"))
```

Can scala compiler guess, that setProduct expects not just a generic entity, but actually something like Product (or it's subclass)? Or there is no way in Scala to implement this even shorter?

Answer (score 1):

Scala compiler won't infer/propagate the type *outside-in*. You could however create implicit conversions like:

```
implicit def stringToSubProduct(uuid: String): SubProduct = { 
  val n = new SubProduct
  n.setUuid(uuid)
  n
}
```

and then just call

```
production.setSubProduct("89a877fa-ddb3-3009-bb24-735ba9f7281c")
```

and the compiler will automatically use the `stringToSubProduct` because it has applicable types on the input and output.

---

**Update:** To have the code better organized I suggest wrapping the `implicit def`s to a companion object, like:

```
case class EntityUUID(uuid: String) {
  uuid.matches("[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}") // possible uuid format check
}
case object EntityUUID {

  implicit def toProduct(e: EntityUUID): Product = {
    val p = new Product
    p.setUuid(e.uuid)
    p
  }

  implicit def toSubProduct(e: EntityUUID): SubProduct = {
    val p = new SubProduct
    p.setUuid(e.uuid)
    p
  }
}
```

and then you'd do

```
production.setProduct(EntityUUID("b1253a77-0585-291f-57a4-53319e897866"))
```

so anyone reading this could have an intuition where to find the conversion implementation.

Regarding your comment about some generic approach (having 30 types), I won't say it's not possible, but I just do not see how to do it. The reflection you used bypasses the type system. If all the 30 cases are the same piece of code, maybe you should reconsider your object design. Now you can still implement the 30 `implicit def`s by calling some method that uses reflection similar what you have provided. But you will have the option to change it in the future on just this one (30) place(s).

Comment: I have about 30 types, that are subclasses of GenericEntity, do I have to write implicit def for all of them like this? Or maybe I can do that just once?